# Finding the Content of a ContentPresenter and setting styles

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, multidatatrigger

I couldn't find an appropriate topic for my problem. I have the following code.

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"                      
                  Width="Auto"/>
<TextBox x:Name="TextBlockFront" >
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=TextBlockFront, Path=IsFocused}" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=ContentPresenter, Path=ContentProperty}" Value="ComboBox"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding ElementName=ContentPresenter,Path=SelectedItem}"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

I want to get the clarification about the second condition of my `MultiTrigger`. I am relative new to WPF and I would appreciate any help in sorting out my doubt.

Expected behaviour:

when the `TextBox` is focused **AND** the `ContentPresenter` is `ComboBox` then I want to set the above properties. If the `ContentPresenter` is `TextBox` then I will set the `Text` property instead of `SelectedItem`

Comment: How and when do you set the `Content` property of the `ContentPresenter`? Can't you just hide the `TextBox` at the same time? Binding to the type of content like this is not supported.

Comment: In place of my ContentPresenter now I have a Combobox so it might change to a TextBox as well. So I want the TextBox to display the content of it. I dont know how well I explained my requirement.

Comment: A `TextBox` can only display strings. You may want to edit your question to clarify your requirements.

Comment: I have edited my question. I hope it's clear now @mm8.

Comment: Read my first comment again.